# EJB testing with TomEE embedded EJBContainer api: java.lang.ClassFormatError exception

Tags: junit, ejb, apache-tomee

I would test my EJB with TomEE embedded EJBContainer.

This is my JUnit test case skeleton:

```
package com.xxx.indexer.scheduler.service;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.xxx.indexer.scheduler.AbstractTest;

public class BookingAuditServiceImplTest extends AbstractTest {

    private static EJBContainer container;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void start() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, "tomee-embedded");
        container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stop() {
        container.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void inject() throws NamingException {
        container.getContext().bind("inject", this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

And these are my maven dependecies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I start the test class, the EJBContainer.createEJBContainer() method throws a java.lang.ClassFormatError exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/embeddable/EJBContainer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read at this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416368/1412839, that the problem is the order of maven dependencies.

I have to declare first the tomee embedded artifact, and after the javaee api, in this way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It works.

Comment: That's it! Now in 2016 the version is: <version>1.7.3</version>

Answer (score 3):

you can replace javax:javaee-api (broken jar) by org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:6.0-4 too and it always works ;)